# Celery worker unresponsive under high load

Tags: python, celery

Under high CPU load, the worker becomes unresponsive, i.e calling `celery -A myapp inspect ping -t 60` results in no responses, while the worker is running. Normal response (pong) resumes shortly after the worker completes its task. This does not always happen under heavy load, but it is not a rare occurance. Here is how I run the worker:

```
executionCommand:
- celery
executionArgs:
- "-A"
- "myapp"
- "worker"
- "--max-tasks-per-child=2"
- "--soft-time-limit=5000"
- "--time-limit=6000"
- "-O"
- "fair"
- "-E"
- "--loglevel=debug"
- "-n"
- "worker@%h"
- "-c"
- "6"
```

My understanding is that since I am not using "solo" pool, I should not be seeing this behaviour. Can someone explain why this is happening ? I am using rabbitmq as my broker.

Using celery 5.0.2, python 3.7.7

Comment: Have you been able to solve this issue?

Comment: No didn't get enough time to get to the bottom of it, have moved to different project since.